# preg_replace, ignore when space added

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this simple piece of code to turn `*text*` into `<strong>text</strong>`.

This all works great, but now I also want to be able to use `*` for making lists, like:

```
* item 1
* item 2
* item 3
```

This will obviously not work with my current code. Is there a way to change the code so that `*` (with a space next to them) are ignored?

This is my current code:

```
$content = preg_replace('#\*(.*?)\*#is', '<strong>$1</strong>', $content);
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I might have been a bit unclear with my example.

So this is the original input:

```
*test*

* test
* test
* test

   *test*
```

This should be formatted as:

```
<strong>test</strong?

* test
* test
* test

   <strong>test</strong>
```

So bassicly `*test*` should show up as `<strong>test</strong>`, unless there is a space right next to the *.
So `* test`, will remain `* test`

It's a little like the formatting used in basecamp

Comment: Will there be a newline at the end of the list?

Comment: Most likely yes, but it depends on the user, they can type it however they want, just if there is a * with a space behind it, it shouldn't be formatted as bold

Comment: Is *behind* supposed to be left (preceding) or right (next to)? o.O

Comment: Next to it, so * test should be ignored, while *test* should be bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `[^\s]` to match any non-space character (you could also use`\b` to get a word boundary, but you would have issues with non-word characters). Your code would be like this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#\*([^\s\*]([^\*]*[^\s\*])?)\*#is', '<strong>$1</strong>', $content);
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, this worked even better, I had some problems with the other one when using a space inside a sentence.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You want the inverse of a character class, i.e. [^ ]. I found this invaluable when starting out with regular expressions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

EDIT: I should have put it in your example.

```
'#[^ ]\*(.*?)\*#is'
```

EDIT: A tested example after clarification in the comments:

```
$in = "
*test*
 * test
  * test

       *test*
";
echo preg_replace('/\*([^ \*]+)\*/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $in);
```

EDIT: Further clarification. When replacing matched characters, like anything between two *'s, it's easier to say 'an asterisk, then anything that isn't an asterisk, followed by a closing asterisk' rather than using a . to match literally the word 'anything' in the plain-english description of what you want. It's also more efficient, having to do with back tracking or something (I'm not sure what the reason is). Since your lists give significance to the trailing spaces I added that to the inverse character class.

Comment: I just checked your example, but that doesn't work, for some reason it removes the last character of every word, so *test*, turns out to be *tes. Looking at the site you gave me now

Comment: *tes? I think you need to elaborate on your example input. I don't see how a replacement can add something that doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: So my input was like this

*test*
  * test
  * test
  *test*

Just to see if it works, but this returns me:
*tes test * test *test*

http://pastebin.com/7Lr7p06A

Comment: Some of the 'test' instances are in italics; I think it's getting formatted. Edit your original post and indent the example and use line breaks where your input has line breaks. However, I think that I figured out what you need and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I just tested this on my input and this works great.

Can you maybe explain a little how you got to there?
The descriptions on regular-expressions.info are a bit inclear

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can i confirm what you are trying to achieve?

You want to change this

```
 * item 1 * item 2 * item 3
```

into

```
* <strong>item 1</strong> * <strong>item 2</strong> * <strong>item 3</strong>
```

Am I correct?